# Eclipselink throwing misleading duplicate entry error with MySQL randomly?

Tags: mysql, jpa, eclipselink

EL (EclipseLink) throwing a random error complaining about duplicate primary key. When observed carefully (by putting logging_level='ALL') the insert statement contains proper data i.e. a unique value in primary column. But EL picks an existing primary key value and quotes as a problem. As I mentioned it happens randomly.

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:Duplicate entry '01e479bb-4c68-a895-95bb-14109fcf1ed3' for key 'PRIMARY' 
Error Code: 1062
```

And it happens with Derby database too. 
Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: The error comes from the database, not Eclipselink, so chances are pretty good there is a problem with the insert.  How is your pk generated, and what statement inserted that problem pk value?

Answer (score 0):

Its actually duplicate record. We are doing high volume (1M inserts to MysQL) with multiple threads. 
But, logging from EL is so confusing and misleading (displays insert stmt with unique values, but showing an existing primary key value - yes its really confusing) that we totally spent so much time looking at wrong places.